# How to create Branch Simmer

Tags: r

I am simulating the arrival of passengers to an airport where they have to pass a verification machine with a uniform distribution (runif(1,1,3)) (in seconds).

Then they have to passe a X-ray machine where we use two triangular distribuitions, one for preparation time and the other for scanning time (both in seconds too) (rtri(1, min = 5, max = 15, mode = 10  and  rtri(1, min = 5, max = 30, mode = 10)).

The passengers arrive acording with a poisson distribution where an average of 2965 passengers arrive per hour.

The number of verification machines is 3 and x-ray machines is 22

BUT there is also the VIP passagers that corresponds 20% of the other passengers and arrive according with a poisson distribution lambda = 0.125 seconds. They also have 4 x-ray machines just for them. The preparation time and scanning time is the same

I am pretty sure that i have to use branch but i dont know how
My code so far:

```
library(triangulr)
library(simmer)
rm(list = ls())
env <- simmer("Security control")
env
```

```
passageiro <- trajectory("passageiro' path" ) %>%
    
  seize("MV") %>%
  timeout(function() runif(1,1,3)) %>%
  release("MV", 1) %>%
    
  seize("MC") %>%
  timeout(function() rtri(1, min = 5, max = 15, mode = 10)) %>%
  timeout(function() rtri(1, min = 5, max = 30, mode = 10)) %>%
  release("MC")
    

env %>%
  add_resource("VM", 3) %>%
  add_resource("CM", 22) %>%
  add_generator("passageiro", passageiro, function() rpois(1,lambda = 2965/3600))

env %>%
  run(until = 10800)
```

MC - Control Machine
VM - Verification Machine

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single arrival process, this is how you can use `branch` to separate VIPs from other passengers (with a 20-80 split):

```r
passageiro <- trajectory("passageiro' path" ) %>%
  ... %>%
  branch(
    function() (runif(1) < 0.2) + 1, continue=c(TRUE, TRUE),
    trajectory() %>%
      ... # normal path,
    trajectory() %>%
      ... # vip path
  ) %>%
  ...
```

But if you have two separate generators, one for normal passengers and other VIPs, then I would just define separate trajectories for them, and that's it. This is much easier.